# Where's the error in this $2=1$ fake proof?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fake-proofs

I'm reading Spivak's *Calculus*:

> **2** What's wrong with the following "proof"? Let $x=y$. Then
>
> $$x^2=xy\tag{1}$$
>
> $$x^2-y^2=xy-y^2\tag{2}$$
>
> $$(x+y)(x-y)=y(x-y)\tag{3}$$
>
> $$x+y=y\tag{4}$$
>
> $$2y=y\tag{5}$$
>
> $$2=1\tag{6}$$

I guess the problem  is in $(3)$, it seems he tried to divide both sides by $(x-y)$. The operation would be acceptable in an example such as:

> $$12x=12\tag{1}$$
>
> $$\frac{12x}{12}=\frac{12}{12}\tag{2}$$
>
> $$x=1\tag{3}$$

I'm lost at what should be causing this, my naive exploration in the nature of both examples came to the following: In the case of $12x=12$, we have an imbalance: We have $x$ in only one side then operations and dividing both sides by $12$ make sense.

Also, In  $\color{red}{12}\color{green}{x}=12$ we have a $\color{red}{coefficient}$ and a $\color{green}{variable}$, the nature of those seems to differ from the nature of

$$\color{green}{(x+y)}\color{red}{(x-y)}=y(x-y)$$

It's like: It's okay to do the thing in $12x=12$, but for doing it on $(x+y)(x-y)=y(x-y)$ we need first to simplify $(x+y)(x-y)$ to $x^2-y^2$.

Comment: I'm at a loss why there is a close vote for NARQ. This is a perfectly valid question, since the OP did not purport that $1 = 2$ but merely sought the flaw in the "proof".

Comment: @Lord_Farin Well, considering that there are *illegal reasons for voting to close/downvoting*, one of the most chosen is because a question is stupid. [I've even created a name for these guys](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402054/show-that-s-capt-cup-t-s-cap-t-cups-cap-t#comment860502_402054). I've spent a lot of time looking at $(3)$ - I was **certain** that the problem was there when it was actually on $(2)$.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I even dare to speculate that those guys didn't earn the [analytical badge.](http://math.stackexchange.com/badges/133/analytical)

Comment: http://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/falseProofs/first1eq2.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy#Division_by_zero

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but I would hypothesise that because there was a different proof that $1=2$ on the front page today someone thought that one was enough! I would tend to agree...there are plenty of places on the internet where one can find the solutions to these problems (there are plenty of questions here which do too...), and I do not think it brings much to the site if everyone starts posting their proofs that $1=2$. One question is okay, two is pushing it, and certainly I will vote to close question number three...

Comment: @user1729 Yes. But *voting to close as a dupe* is different of *voting to close as not a real question*.

Comment: @BandeiraGustavo I didn't say it isn't a real question. Rather, I do not think a flood of such questions is good for the site. If I wanted to try to justify this opinion by trying to fit it into some category that people have come up with, then I would say that it shows a lack of effort from the OP because the solutions are readilly available on the internet. For example, [second result](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=1%3D2+proof).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We have $x = y$, so $x - y = 0$.

**EDIT**: I think I should say more. I'll go through each step:

> $x = y \tag{0}$

This is our premise that $x$ and $y$ are equal.

> $$x^2=xy\tag{1}$$

Note that $x^2 = xx = xy$ by $(0)$. So completely valid.

> $$x^2-y^2=xy-y^2\tag{2}$$

Now we're adding $-y^2$ to *both* sides of $(1$) so completely valid and we can see that it's another way of expressing $0 = 0$ as $x=y$, but nothing wrong here yet.

> $$(x+y)(x-y)=y(x-y)\tag{3}$$
>
> $$x+y=y\tag{4}$$

Step $(3)$ is just basic factoring, and it is around here where things begin to go wrong. For $(4)$ to be a valid consequence of $(3)$, I would need $x - y \neq 0$ as otherwise, we would be dividing by $0$. However, this is in fact what we've done as $x=y$ implies that $x - y =0$. So $(3)-(4)$ is where things go wrong.

> $$2y=y\tag{5}$$
>
> $$2=1\tag{6}$$

As a consequence of not being careful, we end up with gibberish.

Hope this clarifies more!

Comment: Yes. OMG, I'm so damn stupid.

Comment: @BandeiraGustavo Nah, it happens to everyone :)

Comment: @BandeiraGustavo In fact, it's related to the concept of [integral domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain). In a integral domain, $ab=ac$ for some $a\ne0$, if and only if $b=c$. A term is coefficient of variable doesn't make sense here. For this, I'll refer it to [polynomial ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring).

Comment: @BryanUrízar: Bravo my friend. +10 or now +11 ;-)

Comment: @BabakS. Thank you. I never thought I'd get so many up votes :) Just earned a few more badges and getting closer to the 1,000 rep mark :)

Comment: @BryanUrízar: Once you close your eyes and open them, you'll see you are close to $10^4$ and beyond. It won't take your time :-)

Comment: @BabakS. I hope so :)

Comment: Seems like I need to keep my eyes closed longer - still haven't broke the 1000 mark yet :(

Answer (score 11):

We have $x=y$ firstly and from $3$ to $4$ we assume $x\ne y$ **simultaneously**.

Comment: We assume $x\neq y$? I didn't get it. With Bryan's answer, I've figured that $x^2-y^2=0$ and $xy-y^2=0$ and it would end as $0=0$.

Comment: @BandeiraGustavo: I mean when you are going from $3$ to $4$, you naturally assume that $x\neq y$.