# Why does 2 equal 1?

Tags: fake-proofs

A friend showed me this proof:

Proof: 2 = 1

$$Let \space x= y$$

Multiply both sides by x:

$$x^2= xy$$

Subtract $y^2$ from both sides:

$$x^2-y^2= xy-y^2$$

Factor:

$$(x+y)(x-y) = y(x-y)$$

Cancel out $(x-y)$ from both sides:

$$(x+y) = y$$

Simplify (Because $x=y$):

$$y+y=y$$

$$2y = y$$

$$2 = 1$$

Where does the logic break down? Everything is done to both sides.

Comment: Don't divide by $0$. Just...don't do it.

Comment: $0*1=0*99999 \Rightarrow 1=99999$ for sure

Comment: You can't cancel $0$ in the equality $0\cdot1=0\cdot2$

Comment: After the factor is done, $(x-y)=0$ thus both sides become zero and this exercise is finished.  Dupe of these questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417324/wheres-the-error-in-this-2-1-fake-proof and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117998/finding-the-error-in-a-proof

Comment: This must be a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot cancel out the $(x-y)$.  You defined $x=y$, so you end up dividing by $0$.