# A different way to write $(B\cap C)\cup(D \cap E)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=(B\cap C) \cup (D\cap E)$ be a given set. I am looking for a different way to write this. I guess it is somehow possible to "reorder" this by using De Morgan's relations. Unfortunately, I am not successful. Does somebody see how one can write this differently?

Comment: This is _definitely_ not a duplicate of [#402054](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402054)  as it pertains to four different sets.

Comment: I don't see a way to simplify, I think it's basically the simplest way to write down this set.

Comment: @Henno: I don't see the word "simplify" in this page prior to your comment.

Comment: This is a good question and does not deserve to be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Asaf Karagila, there is no option to rewrite your expression in a simpler or more elegant way.

This can be demonstrated graphically:

The following is a [Venn diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) for your case:

[image]

And here is the [Karnaugh-Veitch map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map):

[image]

The two intersecting minterm blocks cannot be replaced by fewer or simpler minterm blocks.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use DeMorgan laws here, but you can use the distributivity of $\cap$ over $\cup$ and vice versa. We have:

$$(B\cap C)\cup(D\cap E)=((B\cap C)\cap D)\cup((B\cap C)\cap E)$$

Using associativity of $\cap$ we get:

$$(B\cap C\cap D)\cup(B\cap C\cap E)$$

It's not simpler than the original form, though. Note that you can do the same thing by distributing $D\cap E$ over the other pair, so we get the following: $$(B\cap C)\cup(D\cap E)=(B\cap C\cap D)\cup(B\cap C\cap E)=(B\cap D\cap E)\cup(C\cap D\cap E)$$